# Java JTable not showing all rows from MySQL

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a problem of JTable, that is when more then 1 rows are returned from MySQL table the JTable shows up only 1 record - (the last one), but when I try simple `System.out.print` it shows all records.
Heres my code:

```
 System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306/";
    String dbName = "smartcart";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "xxx"; 
    String password = "xxx";
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
        cartID=jTextField1.getText().trim();
        if(cartID.matches("(\\w*)") && !cartID.isEmpty())
        {
           jLabel2.setText("Searching.....");
               try {
                        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
                       String query = "SELECT * FROM user_stock WHERE cartID="+cartID;
                       rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                       jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
                        while (rs.next()) {
                              jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                               new Object [][] {
                                  {rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("product_name"), rs.getString("product_code"), rs.getString("product_quantity"), rs.getString("product_price"), "0"}
                               },
                                new String [] {
                                  "Product No.", "Product Name", "Product Code", "Product Quantity", "Product Price", "Discount"
                                   }
                                ));
                        }
      conn.close();
      System.out.println("Disconnected from database");

                        }
               catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating a new TableModel for each returned row instead of one model for all rows:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM user_stock WHERE cartID="+cartID;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String [] {
                              "Product No.", "Product Name", "Product Code", "Product Quantity", "Product Price", "Discount" });
 jTable1.setModel(model);
 while (rs.next()) {
     model.addRow(new Object [] {
               rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("product_name"), rs.getString("product_code"), rs.getString("product_quantity"), rs.getString("product_price"), "0"});       
 }
```

Caveats: I have not tested nor executed the code above but it should not be hard to fix typos or missing parenthesis.

Now, you can also simplify your life and reuse directly [`ResulSetTableModel`](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch25/Fig25_28_31/ResultSetTableModel.java) which does it all for you.

Comment: @user210068 typo that has been fixed. Refresh your screen

Answer (score 1):

1) `XxxTableModel` is re_created in endless loop, a new model on every of loops

2) don't to create a new `XxxTableModel`, nor inside `try - catch - finally` block

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
```

3) not reason include with

```
new Object [][] {
{
rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("product_name"), rs.getString("product_code"),
   rs.getString("product_quantity"), rs.getString("product_price"), "0"}
}, 
new String [] {"Product No.", "Product Name", "Product Code", "Product Quantity",
  "Product Price", "Discount" }
));
```

4) reuse `XxxTableModel`

5) then to add a new row inside JDBC to the `XxxTableModel` that is already initalized as local variable

6) there is potential issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) all updates to the already visible GUI must be done on `Event Dispatch Thread`

- by wrapping inside `invokeLater`
- invoke JDBC from `Runnable#Thread` (by wrapping inside `invokeLater` for each of row)
- invoke from `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 0):

You muste create only one TableModel for the whole ResultSet.